# Неубиваемый сервис

Tags: android

Нашел один проект который в сервисе создает уведомления. Собственно у меня возникли вопросы при изучении данного проекта.

1. Что за класс Constants с интерфейсом ACTION и константами. Для чего они нужны и обязательно писать так: "com.truiton.foregroundservice.action.main" или можно свое слово написать типа main, play и т.д.
2. Почему именно FOREGROUND_SERVICE = 101;, а не скажем 100500?

Не только этот пример нашел еще один готовый проект такого же типа муз. проигрыватель там тоже есть класс констант. Не могу понять для чего он

Класс сервиса

```
public class ForegroundService extends Service {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "ForegroundService";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION)) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Received Start Foreground Intent ");
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            notificationIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.MAIN_ACTION);
            notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                    notificationIntent, 0);

            Intent previousIntent = new Intent(this, ForegroundService.class);
            previousIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.PREV_ACTION);
            PendingIntent ppreviousIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
                    previousIntent, 0);

            Intent playIntent = new Intent(this, ForegroundService.class);
            playIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.PLAY_ACTION);
            PendingIntent pplayIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
                    playIntent, 0);

            Intent nextIntent = new Intent(this, ForegroundService.class);
            nextIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.NEXT_ACTION);
            PendingIntent pnextIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
                    nextIntent, 0);

            Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.truiton_short);

            Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setContentTitle("Truiton Music Player")
                    .setTicker("Truiton Music Player")
                    .setContentText("My Music")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setLargeIcon(
                            Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(icon, 128, 128, false))
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setOngoing(true)
                    .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_previous,
                            "Previous", ppreviousIntent)
                    .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play, "Play",
                            pplayIntent)
                    .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_next, "Next",
                            pnextIntent).build();
            startForeground(Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID.FOREGROUND_SERVICE,
                    notification);
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.PREV_ACTION)) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Clicked Previous");
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.PLAY_ACTION)) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Clicked Play");
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.NEXT_ACTION)) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Clicked Next");
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(
                Constants.ACTION.STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION)) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Received Stop Foreground Intent");
            stopForeground(true);
            stopSelf();
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "In onDestroy");
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // Used only in case of bound services.
        return null;
    }
}
```

Main

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button stopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        startButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        stopButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button1:
                Intent startIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ForegroundService.class);
                startIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION);
                startService(startIntent);
                break;
            case R.id.button2:
                Intent stopIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ForegroundService.class);
                stopIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION);
                startService(stopIntent);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

Класс констант

```
public class Constants {
    public interface ACTION {
        public static String MAIN_ACTION = "com.truiton.foregroundservice.action.main";
        public static String PREV_ACTION = "com.truiton.foregroundservice.action.prev";
        public static String PLAY_ACTION = "com.truiton.foregroundservice.action.play";
        public static String NEXT_ACTION = "com.truiton.foregroundservice.action.next";
        public static String STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION = "com.truiton.foregroundservice.action.startforeground";
        public static String STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION = "com.truiton.foregroundservice.action.stopforeground";
    }

    public interface NOTIFICATION_ID {
        public static int FOREGROUND_SERVICE = 101;
    }
}
```

Comment: Наверняка есть те кто знает, но жадничает пару предложений написать и пояснить мои два несложных вопроса :)

Answer (score 2):

1. Это такой способ хранения констант - все в одном месте, удобно редактировать, удобно использовать.
   В интерфейсах их хранят, чтобы в любом классе имплементировать этот интерфейс и использовать константы как "родные" по имени (в приведённом коде не используется), но сейчас есть `import static`, позволяющий импортировать статические члены любого класса.
   ACTION может быть любой строкой, но добавление к нему имени пакета рекомендуется для обеспечения уникальности (ведь компонент может быть доступен другим приложениям).
2. А почему нет))) это идентификатор уведомления - может быть любым числом.

Comment: Вполне понятно объяснили. Спасибо. :)